# NServiceBus - EventHandler Design / Naming Conventions for Multiple Responsibilities

Tags: nservicebus

I want to raise an event internal to a service, then send two commands on the bus (one internal to the service, one external). I don't think the code to do both of these tasks should be in the same event handler, but from all the examples I've seen online the naming convention seems to be [NameOfEvent]Handler.

If I were to create two event handlers (or really just describe what the handler is doing, because "FooHandler" doesn't really tell you what the object will do) what's the current thought on best practice for naming conventions?

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 1):

If these are fundamentally different responsibilities, you could have them set up as different endpoints, each subscribed to the event, each with a handler call [NameOfEvent]Handler.